# Intraclass correlation with labeled data points

Tags: correlation, intraclass-correlation

I want to run ICC on my data set, but the label of each point matters.

In regular ICC, these data sets would be equivalent:

```
|    X          |    X
| X      X      | X      X
|    X   X      |    X   X
| X             | X
|      X        |      X
|___________    |___________
```

However, let's label each point. This essentially means that points are evaluated with other points of the same label, not with every single point in the set. The different values for each label are then combined into a single coefficient. For example, these data sets would not be equivalent:

```
|    ❌         |    X
| X      X      | ❌      ❌
|    X   ❌     |    X   X
| ❌            | X
|      X        |      ❌
|___________    |___________
```

Since the red points are in different spots, the two graphs are evaluated differently.

Is there a test like this?

Comment: They're called labels.  Coloring data means transforming it so that it has a given variance matrix.

Comment: @NeilG Alright, thanks. I edited the question to use label instead of color.